# Storing occurence of random number

Tags: python

Say I have something like this in Python

```
from random import randint

for i in range(50):
   print randint(1, 10)
```

How would I go about storing how many times it printed 1 how many times it printed 2 and so forth.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @MorganThrapp I have tried, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: To get you started, you could use `freq = [0] * 11` list where `freq[r]` stores how many times `r` occurs.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I don't really get what you're saying, could you show me an example of it?

Comment: If you don't understand what is list and how to use it then you should read a book (any book) about Python first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python the `Counter` is usually used to count the number of occurrences. You just have to save the generated random value in a variable and update the counter in each iteration.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import Counter
import random

cntr = Counter()
for _ in range(50):
    rnd = random.randint(1, 10)
    cntr.update([rnd])
    print(rnd)

for value, count in cntr.most_common():
    print("%d was generated %d times" % (value, count))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way without Counter. 
Just simple dict usage.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from random import randint

info = {}

for i in range(50):
    rand_val = randint(1, 10)

    if rand_val not in info.keys():
        info[rand_val] = 0

    info[rand_val] += 1

    print(rand_val)

print()
for value, cnt in info.items():
    print("value %s is generated %s times" % (value, cnt))
```